# Repository Pattern/ UOW Pattern with different database platforms

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Does anyone have an experience coming up with a decent repository/UOW pattern while using different database technologies (in this case sql and informix).

I struggle cause I cannot use EF against the informix database and would like to keep things as uniform as possible but at the same time I would like to avoid to much model transformation.

Comment: You're really asking *"what's a good .NET ORM for Informix"*, aren't you ?

Answer (score 1):

The repository pattern already provides the flexibility you need to achieve this. **Define an interface for your repository. Now add two implementations, one for SQL Server and one for Informix.**

The actual problem you seem to have is not the pattern to use it, but the technical infrastructure to connect to both SQL Server and Informix. Here, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) could be a solution, because it supports both SQL Server and Informix as far as I know.

Or if you want to keep EF with the SQL Server DB, just use Dapper with Informix - the repositories will nicely hide that fact from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since in DDD, database is an implementation detail, what **theDmi** has provided is a really good solution if you don't have to make context data available in one or the other ORM solutions you're utilizing (at least without fiddling with the creation of some sort of set of "bridging" objects).  I'd also go with this if there is some business reason that this data should be "separated" out into different repositories for some reason where it's important to know what came from Sql Server and what came from Informix.

However, If you'd rather view it all as one bundle of data, another solution would be to link in the Informix data in Sql Server itself. Then you should be able to leverage views or stored procedures to get the Informix data as though Sql Server is hosting it. And as you probably know, EF provides some means of mapping objects to stored procedures and views.

Of course, this solution would highly depend upon how much control you have over the Sql Server administration and schema.